# Showing the attachment for a page?

Tags: attachments

I have the following function, it displays the attachments of a post, however it shows the full size, how can i show a limited number of attachments and also a smaller version like a thumbnail.

```
function page_thumbnails() {
$argsThumb = array(
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null
);
$attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
        echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'post-thumbnail', false, false).'" />';
    }

}
}
add_shortcode('page-thumbs', 'page_thumbnails');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size);
```

Specify the size parameter as follows;

> `$size (string/array) (optional)`
>
> Size of the image shown for an image attachment: either a string keyword (**thumbnail, medium, large or full**)
>   or a 2-item array representing width and height in pixels, e.g.
>   **array(32,32)**. As of Version 2.5, this parameter does not affect the
>   size of media icons, which are always shown at their original size.

Excerpted from the WordPress Codex on  [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Your final code might look like,

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'small').'" />';
```

Or

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, array(100, 100).'" />';
```

If you want to specify via array.

Use,

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

...to specify custom image sizes.

Comment: how about limiting the number of attachments to show, and also it is showing attachments from other pages. since i am using a page to category plugin, i think i am missing a bit of code something like parent child